# ffmpeg cutet video lose sound last seconds

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

Hello I use this command and last seconds of a video sound is mute.

```
ffmpeg -ss <start_time> -i <output_result> -t <duration_of_video> -c copy <name_of_a_file.mp4>
```

So last 2 or 3 to 5,6 second are muted no sound only video.When I play it in VLC Player is stop 1 second before  when i post on Instagram is playing till the end but 2-3 sec to 5-6 sec before that sound stops only video.I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.Any suggestion Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in -c copy option for default codec. Instead I use -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec libx264.SO command is:

> ffmpeg -ss  -i  -t 
>   -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec libx264

Comment: `-c copy` doesn't mean *default codec*. It means [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy).

Comment: Yes I miss that but this was a problem to produce more length video with no sound in the end.